# Color Cells with Null-value in Grafana table

Tags: postgresql, grafana

I want to color a cell in a Grafana table filled with values from a Postgresql with a red background when its value is NULL.

It seems Thresholds can only be used for the color when you have numeric values and with an Override I can't get it to work. Any ideas?

I created a value mapping, but how do I catch the Null-Value? Leaving the Value field blank did not work, entering "NULL" did not work. I tried to populate a value by using "What to show when there is no value", which catched and transformed the value, but this also didn't work vor changing the BG-Color:

[image: settings for value mapping]

[image: how table looks]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use value mapping (e. g. for special null value). See doc for more details: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels-visualizations/configure-value-mappings/#table-example

Comment: OP already uses color mapping